# Generate list of all installed (La)TeX files

Tags: texmf, scripts, file-lookup

I'm trying to write a script (Perl) for the general public which would need to have a list of all installed TeX files of a certain type, e.g. `.sty` and/or `.cls` files or only plainTeX files (`.tex`), depending on the used options.

I know I can search for specific files using the `kpsewhich` program, but it seems to have no 'list all' mode (which is understandable). My second idea was to parse all `ls-R` files which should work, but would be more work.

**Is there a way to get all TeX source files or only the `ls-R` files from `kpsewhich` or another tool?**

At best this should work for both TeX Live and MikTeX on all supported operation systems. However, my main target is TeX Live under Linux. As fall-back solution I would hard code the default paths and allow the user to change these using a configuration file.

Comment: This is not my area of knowledge, but MacTeX provides a program called TeX Live Utility which is a GUI for `tlmgr` which can list all the installed packages: http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html#list____only_installed___collections_schemes_pkg____ Maybe you could utilise its approach.

Comment: Or you could probably use shell `find /usr/local/texlive -name "*.sty"`.

Comment: Thanks @Harrold, I know about such possibilities. I'm trying to avoid them and #use the official tools to get the official paths.

Comment: You might want to use the fact that in modern TeX distributions, `texlua` is a standalone lua interpreter.

Comment: @mbork: So call `texlua` with Lua code from inside a Perl script??? Or are your trying to tell me to not use Perl at all but Lua?

Comment: @Martin: I meant only that while assuming that, for example, an average windows user has perl installed is risky, you may safely assume that he's got lua if he's got TeX.  So if you use lua, this should work on all platforms supporting MikTeX/texlive.

Comment: All `kpsewhich` knowledge is based on `texmf.cnf`, on `ls-R` files and on disk scanning for files in trees not specifically marked as "no `ls-R`". It doesn't perform glob searches.

Comment: @egreg: I know, that's fine and exactly what I also want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a shell script, which finds all bst,sty, and cls files which are available
with kpsewhich.

```
 #!/bin/sh
# file: ~/bin/TeXFiles.sh
# lists all available 
# TeX class files   -> option cls 
# TeX style files   -> option sty
# bibtex style files    -> option bst
#
# with the help
# of kpsewhich and creates a 
# bstFiles.lst, clsFiles.lst, styFiles.lst
# without any parameter all files are created.
#
# Herbert Voss <hvoss@tug.org>
#
CLS_STYLEFILE=clsFiles.lst
STY_STYLEFILE=styFiles.lst
BST_STYLEFILE=bstFiles.lst
DIRLIST=TeXtree.lst
version='$Id: TeXFiles.sh,v 0.1 2001/08/13'
progname=`echo $0 | sed 's%.*/%%'`
echo "$version"
usage="Usage: TeXFiles.sh [-version | cls | sty | bst] 
       Default is without any Parameters,
       so that all files will be created"

#
# MS-DOS and MS-Windows define $COMSPEC or $ComSpec and use ';' to separate
# directories in path lists whereas Unixes uses ':'.
# $SEP holds the right character to be used by the scripts.
#
if test -z "$COMSPEC" && test -z "$ComSpec"; then SEP=':'; else SEP=';'; fi
#
# Add the location of the script to the PATH if necessary.  This must
# be done before kpsewhich can be called, and thus cannot be put into
# mktex.opt.
#
dirname=`echo $0 | sed 's%/*[^/][^/]*$%%'`
echo "Actual Dir: $dirname"
case $dirname in            # $dirname correct?
  "")                   # Do nothing
      ;;
  /* | [A-z]:/*)            # / -> Absolute name 
      PATH="$dirname$SEP$PATH" ;;
   *)                   # other -> Relative name
      PATH="`pwd`/$dirname$SEP$PATH" ;;
esac                    # end of case
#
# A copy of some stuff from mktex.opt, so we can run in the presence of
# terminally damaged ls-R files.
#
if test "x$1" = x--help || test "x$1" = x-help; then
  echo "$usage"
  exit 0
elif test "x$1" = x--version || test "x$1" = x-version; then
  echo "`basename $0` $version"
  kpsewhich --version
  exit 0
fi
#
# find the directories with locate. teTeX has files ls-R to hold
# the tex-tree
#
test $# = 0 && {
  OIFS=$IFS; IFS=$SEP; set x `kpsewhich --show-path=ls-R 2>/dev/null`; shift; IFS=$OIFS
}
echo 'Delete old *files.lst, if present'
case "$1" in
    "cls")
    rm -f $CLS_STYLEFILE
    touch $CLS_STYLEFILE        # create new file
    ;;
    "sty")
    rm -f $STY_STYLEFILE
    touch $STY_STYLEFILE        # create new file
    ;;
    "bst")
    rm -f $BST_STYLEFILE
    touch $BST_STYLEFILE        # create new file
    ;;
    *)                  # all other
    rm -f $CLS_STYLEFILE $STY_STYLEFILE $BST_STYLEFILE
    touch $CLS_STYLEFILE $STY_STYLEFILE $BST_STYLEFILE 
    ;;
esac
echo "looking for all *-style files in the latex tree";
#locate ls-R > $DIRLIST
#for TEXMFLSR in `cat $DIRLIST`; do     # go through the dirs
for TEXMFLSR in $@ ; do     # go through the dirs
  echo "Dir: <$TEXMFLSR>"
case "$1" in                # list all files with suffix bst
    "cls")
    find $TEXMFLSR -name *.cls >> $CLS_STYLEFILE
    ;;
    "sty")
    find $TEXMFLSR -name *.sty >> $STY_STYLEFILE
    ;;
    "bst")
    find $TEXMFLSR -name *.bst >> $BST_STYLEFILE
    ;;
    *) 
    find $TEXMFLSR -name *.cls >> $CLS_STYLEFILE
    find $TEXMFLSR -name *.sty >> $STY_STYLEFILE
    find $TEXMFLSR -name *.bst >> $BST_STYLEFILE
    ;;
esac

  echo "done!"
done
#echo "list saved in $STYLEFILE"
#echo `wc -l $CLS_STYLEFILE`        # only for information
#
# this is the end my friends ... Jim Morrison and the Doors in "The End"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for t in `kpsewhich --expand-var '$TEXMF' | tr -d '{}!' | tr ',' ' '`; do
  find $t -type f -ls
done | grep '\.[sc][tl][ys]$' | awk '{print $NF}'
```