# How to programmatically detect if a LaTeX package is installed?

Tags: packages, compiling, automation

I am writing a program, and I want it to do different things depending on which LaTeX packages have been installed.  My current solution is to automatically generate simple `.tex` files that `\usepackage` the packages I care about and then automatically check if `pdflatex` can compile them or not.  This solution seems slow and fragile.  What is a better solution?

Edit: The program I am writing is in Python.

Comment: Sorry, you want to check this from a program/script and not from inside a LaTeX document? The latter would be shown in [Conditional “if a package is available”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15306/conditional-if-a-package-is-available).

Comment: See also [Generate list of all installed (La)TeX files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23840/generate-list-of-all-installed-latex-files) which has a similar background, i.e. a script which wants to get a list of *all* installed LaTeX packages. In your case you would just need to check that list. However, this is platform and probably LaTeX distribution dependent.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Do you want to detect from inside LaTeX? If so, there is

```
\IfFileExists{foobar.sty}{true}{false}
```

If you're external, there is `kpsewhich foobar.sty`, which gives you the path to the foobar.sty that latex would use.

Comment: Is `kpsewhich` available only if some TeX distribution is installed? I'm thinking to use it to test if there is TeX compiler installed.

Comment: @Sigur: yes. You might get better results with trying to run `which tex` and checking the return code of that, assuming unix.