# Issue installing minted on Windows 10

Tags: miktex, minted

I'm currently trying to install Minted on Windows 10 and TexMaker.  To do this, I'm following the installation instructions [here](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf).  My current issue is that I followed these instructions, and when attempting to compile a small file to verify the installation is correct, TexMaker hangs (and doesn't even throw an error).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[mathescape,
               linenos=false,
               numbersep=5pt,
               gobble=2,
               %showspaces,
               frame=lines,
               framesep=2mm,
               %fontfamily=
               %fontsize=\tiny{matlab}
               ]{Matlab} 
     for i=1:10 
        i=i+1;
     end
 \end{minted}
\end{document}
```

I'm aware to compile a file using minted one has to invoke -shell-escape.  I ran `pdflatex -shell-escape | pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex` to compile it.  When I run with TexMaker's QuickBuild (which I have setup as "PdfLaTex+View PDF", I quickly get the following errors:

`! Package minted Error: You must invoke LaTeX with the -shell-escape flag.See the minted package documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \begin`

`! Emergency stop.<read 2> \begin{document}`

`! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!`

I also get the warning:

`Package ifplatform Warning:shell escape is disabled, so I can only detect \ifwindows.`

I've verified I have python version 3.4.3 installed, and running `pip install Pygments` outputs `Requirement already satisfied`, along with the directory Pygments is installed in.  I've verified Pygments is updated using `pip` and `--upgrade` (although it just tells me it's up to date, and not which version).

I've also checked that I have all the correct packages installed using `\IfFileExists{foobar.sty}{true}{false}` as suggested in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31852/how-to-programmatically-detect-if-a-latex-package-is-installed).  I get `true` for each package except for `shellesc.sty`, which I'll look into after posting this (I'm unsure if I need it yet).

Finally, I've used the above method to check if `minted.sty` is installed, which it is.

Does anyone know what might be causing TexMaker to hang, or further things I can try to at least get it to give me an error?

**EDIT:**
While attempting to check if I'm compiling through LuaTex (which I believe I'm not, but haven't verified yet), I've found that my `--shell-escape` build was causing TexMaker to hang even when attempting to compile a file without `minted.sty`.  This leads me to believe that running `pdflatex -shell-escape | pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex` is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `pdflatex -shell-escape %.tex|pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex` works.  This doesn't open up the compiled document in the internel PDF viewer, but adding `"C:/Program Files (x86)/Adobe/Reader 11.0/Reader/AcroRd32.exe" %.pdf` onto the end of it seems to.  I'll leave this question up for a few hours in case I'm doing something egregiously wrong, but this appears to solve my problem.

Comment: I don't see why you use a pipe. `pdflatex -synctex=1  -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape` (or `--enable-write18` under MiKTeX) `%.tex` works fine. Comment aside: Acrobat Reader locks .pdf files, and you have to close it before making a new compilation. You'd better use the much lighter and faster `SumatraPDF`.

Comment: For your suggestion, do I use `--enable-write18` in place of `-shell-escape`, or which part?

Comment: Your distribution is MiKTeX? Personally, I have `--enable-write18` because I read so once, but I think it understands both (I use it for `auto-pst-pdf`with pstricks files).

Comment: I'm on MiKTex.  It seems like both of them likely work and serve a similar purpose.